# Does WordPress have a page-specific equivalent to get_post_meta()?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'd like to attach metadata to pages, but as far as I can tell, this is limited to posts in WordPress.  Are there any methods to add arbitrary metadata to pages for later extraction and use it in PHP theme code?  If so, how?

Comment: Any of the down-voters care to say how this question could be improved, or offer anything useful at all?

Comment: If my answer was helpful / solved your problem, it would be in good form to accept it (click the grey checkmark below the votes on the left side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

Note: *I'm assuming the downvotes have to do with a perception of "lack of research" or "too broad" - but after doing my own research, it appears there aren't any good / clear resources on this.*

Note that the documentation *does reference pages*, but it isn't super clear.

First, understand that Pages and Posts are (essentially) the same thing in WordPress.

All pages, posts, and "custom post types" are stored in the `posts` table in the database.

Further, all of the `get_post_meta`, etc. type functions are applicable to pages, posts, and custom post types.

A page (or post or custom post type) is referenced by the `$post->ID` - which indicates which record in the DB the metadata is attached to, regardless of whether it's a page, post, etc.

So - armed with this information:

1. You can absolute attach metadata to a *page* using [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta).
2. You can absolutely retreive metadata for a page using [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).
3. Additionally, you can [add_meta_box](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) and more to pages as well as posts.

**Note:**
When editing a page in WordPress, the "custom fields" (which is the `post_meta` for the page) metabox is not shown by default.  In order to view the "custom fields" metabox, be sure to:

1. When editing the page, click on the "Screen Options" tab in the upper right corner.
2. In the section that appears, find the "Custom Fields" checkbox.  Check it.
3. Click the "Screen Options" tab again to make it go away.
4. The "Custom Fields" metabox should now be showing, below the content editor (and possibly below other metaboxes).

Comment: This is correct.  The unfortunate part is that WordPress' post editor includes a place to enter metadata, but the page editor does not.  Requiring us to enter page metadata programmatically is a turn-off to using this.

Comment: @BillHayden - you can absolutely enable "Custom fields" (aka "post meta") for pages.  When editing a page, go to the top-right "Screen options" tab.  Click it, which drops down the screen options.  One of the checkboxes is "Custom Fields".  Check that box, and voila - you've got post meta on your page.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I've been looking for.